# Can I somehow filter a Youtube Mix?

Tags: youtube-api

I want to only play videos with a specified view count (<500) to find new/undiscovered Music.

Is that somehow possible with youtube-api?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the help center, take the tour to see what and How to Ask. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt

Comment: Will do thank you.